# opening and closing using OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv

How do you implement the techniques of image processing, opening, and closing using OpenCV with C#? Can anyone give me an example?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you are using EmguCV (as go4sri assumed) the Code snippet for Opening EmguCV would look like this:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> src = new Image<Gray, Byte>( "Your Image.png" );
Image<Gray, Byte> dst = new Image<Gray, Byte>( src.Width, src.Height );
StructuringElementEx element = new StructuringElementEx( 3, 3, 1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_ELEMENT_SHAPE.CV_SHAPE_CROSS );

CvInvoke.cvMorphologyEx( src, dst, IntPtr.Zero, element, CV_MORPH_OP.CV_MOP_OPEN, 1 );

ImageViewer.Show( dst, "Your morphed Image" );
```

For Closing you would just need to replace the Enum

```
CV_MORPH_OP.CV_MOP_CLOSE
```

For more Information about these functions visit [EmguCV Doc](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html)

Comment: What is `grey` in `grey.Width` and `grey.Height`?

Comment: Oh didn't fix that. It's from a unit test. You can replace gray with src.

Comment: Since at least version 2.4.0 (it's the oldest version I have) of EmguCV, you can call MorphologyEx or _MorphologyEx directly on the image object instead of using CvInvoke.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). You can use the `MorphologyEx` method which implements both simple and complex morphology based operations

Answer (score 0):

To implement opening you call erode followed by dilate.
Closing  is done by calling first dilate then erode.

References:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html